# How to debug Rails' "cannot load such a file -- sprokets/railtie" message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I have a webapp working perfectly fine locally, but when I come to start up the server in the production environment, I get this error:

> "C:/RailsInstall/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sass-rails=4.0.5/lib/sass/railtie.rb:1:in 'require': cannot load such a file -- sprockets/railtie (Load Error)"

What's gone wrong? How might I fix it?

If you need any other information, please let me know and I can update. "bundle install" runs fine, says that my bundle is complete.

Comment: Did you copy and paste that error message or type it in? There's a spelling mistake in `sprockets` which is weird if you copy pasted it

Comment: No, typed it in :) corrected the typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest running `bundle install` prior to running the server in the production environment as that gem may not have been installed on the server. Also, a possible cause of the error could be if the `sprockets` gem is included in your Gemfile but is located inside a group that is not being loaded by Bundler because of using the `--without` parameter.

Comment: Thanks man, I worked out the problem last night and it's along the lines you're saying. Basically it was a case of having gems of the wrong version. Started the environment from scratch again, kept running "gem install <whatever>", "rails s", looking what was missing, repeat. Solved the problem, albeit in a very longwinded way!